# Get a list of Entity Framework validation errors

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm building an Asp.net Core 2 MVC application that references a vendor's database.  While we have attempted to ensure that the required data elements for the application are present, inevitably some data-quality issues will ensue (their application's rules don't require some fields that we plan to use).  I'd like to use a model's data-validation rules to display data-quality issues.

Assuming that I have an `Employee` model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An Email Address is required")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to be able to include an indicator in the `Index` method for the `EmployeesController` that a particular record has a validation error, perhaps displaying a warning symbol to the right of the employee's name.  Clicking the symbol would show a page that listed all of the model's validation errors for that employee.

** edit **

This application is read-only; there will be no C_UD to the `Employee` model.  I'm really just interested in displaying validation issues during the Read (if this is possible).

** / edit **

Questions:

- Are the validation messages added to the model when they are retrieved from the database?  if so, can they be accessed in a Razor view?
- If I'm using a ViewModel, can the validations be transferred (via AutoMapper) from the model?

Comment: The model you have shown looks like a ViewModel to me. As such, any errors (such as `Required` properties) can be caught and displayed to the user before hitting the database by checking the `ModelState` and returning a `BadRequest(ModelState)` result if there are problems. See [Handling Model State Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#handling-model-state-errors)